# Applet not working on html

Tags: java, html, applet

I have created a japplet called PaintApplet in netbeans, I got the .jar file of it and put it in a folder with the html file, the html file is this:

```
 <html>
<body>
<APPLET ARCHIVE="PaintApplet.jar" CODE=PaintApplet.class  WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=500>


</APPLET>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Java installed on the browser?

Comment: Yes, it asks me to run it and I click ok, but then nothing happens it shows the size of the applet, buts its grey and has that jigsaw piece logo in the middle. Nothing loads, not even the applet loading screen

Answer (score 0):

Remove .class from the tag and add the package name if the class is not in the default package.

```
<APPLET 
    ARCHIVE="PaintApplet.jar" 
    CODE="com.org.PaintApplet"  
    WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=500>
</APPLET>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html

> - code is the name of the applet class
> - archive is the name of jar file containing the applet and its resources
> - width is the width of the applet
> - height is the height of the applet

Or use an object tag:

```
<OBJECT 
  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
  width="800" height="500">
  <PARAM name="code" value="com.org.PaintApplet">
  <PARAM name="archive" value="PaintApplet.jar">
</OBJECT>
```

Also, make sure you have installed the latest JRE version (1.7.0 update 17 currently) since some browsers will block applets if the java plugin is not up to date.

Comment: Think you're confusing it with running an application, `java -jar ...`

Comment: No, that doesn't matter - you can add `.class` without any issues (just tested)